# how to zoom page in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want to use a button to zoom my page not just for images

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I want to share a few suggestions for you to try to improve your post and future posts, try to share more information, like, what you have tried, a snippet of the code that you have and what you are trying to achieve, in this case, I'm not sure if you want to add a zoom feature or a floating button. I would advise you to edit your question with more information.

Comment: Check the tags you used. You tagged this "zoom-sdk", this is the SDK for the Zoom platform. Did you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are looking for this, [zoom_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/zoom_widget), but it uses gesture inst

```
Zoom(
    width: 1800,
    height: 1800,
    child: Center(
        child: Text("Happy zoom!!"),
    )
);
```

OR

[zoomer](https://pub.dev/packages/zoomer), use controller to setScale:

```
  ZoomerController _zoomerController = ZoomerController(initialScale: 1.0);
  String _zoomDetails = "Zoom";  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    _zoomerController.onZoomUpdate((){
      setState(() {
        _zoomDetails = "Scale = "+ _zoomerController.scale.toStringAsFixed(2);
        _zoomDetails += "\nRotation = "+ _zoomerController.rotation.toStringAsFixed(2);
        _zoomDetails += "\nOffset = ("+ _zoomerController.offset.dx.toStringAsFixed(2)+","+_zoomerController.offset.dy.toStringAsFixed(2)+")";
      });
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Zommer Example"),),
      body:
        Center(child:
        Stack(
          children: [
            Align(alignment: Alignment.topCenter,child: SizedBox(height: 150,child: Text(_zoomDetails,textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),))),
            Center(
              child: 
                Zoomer(
                  enableTranslation: true,
                  enableRotation: true,
                  clipRotation: true,
                  maxScale: 2,
                  minScale: 0.5,
                  background:BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                  height: 300,
                  width: 300,
                  controller: _zoomerController,
                  child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),height: 200,width: 200,child: FlutterLogo(),)),
            ),
          ])),
    );
  }
}
```